# Python import statement with argument

Tags: python, python-import

I am using `numpy` in one of my libraries. No surprise there.

One user would essentially like a copy of my project where I don't use the default `numpy`, but the one bundled with `autograd`. For instance, let's say I have a dumb function:

```
import numpy
def doSomething(x):
   return numpy.sin(x)
```

They would like a copy of the library where all of these `import numpy` are replaced by `from autograd import numpy`:

```
from autograd import numpy
def doSomething(x):
   return numpy.sin(x)
```

This would allow them to easily compute gradients and jacobians of my functions.

I would like to know what the easiest way to handle this is without copying the whole codebase and replacing all of these lines.

Options I am aware of:

1. I could make a copy of the codebase (`lib` and `lib_autograd`) where the first uses `import numpy`, and the second uses `from autograd import numpy`. This is bad because then I have to maintain two codebases.
2. I could automatically import from `autograd` if it is available:

   ```
   try:
       from autograd import numpy
   except ImportError:
       import numpy
   ```

   The reason I do not want to do this is that many people have highly optimized `numpy` installs, whereas `autograd` might not. So I want to give the user an option which version to import. Forcing the user to use the `autograd` version if they have it seems bad since it would not be apparent to the user what is going on, and would require the user to uninstall `autograd` if they want to use the library with their default `numpy` installation.

So what are my options?

Ideally there would be a way of doing something like passing a parameter to the `import` statement (I do realize that you can't do this):

```
useAutograd = False
from lib(useAutograd) import doSomething
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have 'conditional' import with:

```
try:
    from autograd import numpy
except ImportError:
    import numpy
```

One of other options is to have environment variable that switches whether you want to use `numpy` from `autograd` or regular one, because here you either use `autograd.numpy` (if it exists) or `numpy`. You don't have an option to use `numpy` if there is `autograd` module/package.

To elaborate on giving user an option to switch, here is one possibility:

```
import os

if os.environ.get('AUTOGRADNUMPY'):
    try:
        from autograd import numpy
    except ImportError:
        import numpy
else:
    import numpy
```

Having environment variable `AUTOGRADNUMPY` set to `True` (or anything else that is not empty string) when you want to load `numpy` from `autograd` package. If it is not set or doesn't exist, regular `numpy` is imported.

All of this stands if user has at least `numpy` installed.

Comment: This might be the way yo go. I will think about it

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
try:
    from autograd import numpy as np
except ImportError:
    import numpy as np

...
...
np.sum(..)
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I am looking for here. Because if a user has Autograd on their system, it would use that version. I want to be able to somehow define an import that let's the user choose "at import time".

Comment: Modifying the question now to make that clearer...